# Modern UI using QT and PyQt5

Tags: json, pyqt5, pyside2

I want to make a modern UI using PYQT5 but when I put loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui) it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\gui_industry\main.py", line 59, in <module>
windows = MainWindow()
File "C:\Users\mariam\Desktop\gui_industry\main.py", line 44, in __init__
loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
File "C:\Users\mariam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\Custom_Widgets\Widgets.py", line 2157, in loadJsonStyle
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(str(QMainWindow["icon"])))
TypeError: setWindowIcon(self, QIcon): argument 1 has unexpected type 
'PySide2.QtGui.QIcon'
```

I'm applying it to PySide, but I haven't been able to apply it to PyQt5. I've been working on this for a while, and it's something that hasn't let me move forward, and this is the code

```
`class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
    self.setMinimumSize(850, 600)

    ########################################################################
    # APPLY JSON STYLESHEET
    ########################################################################
    # self = QMainWindow class
    # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow / user_interface class

    self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

windows = MainWindow()
windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`
JSON

```
            {
             "QMainWindow":[
                           {
                              "tittle":"Industry4.0",
                              "icon":":/icons/icons/upload-cloud.svg",
                              "frameless": true,
                              "transluscentBg": true,
                               "sizeGrip": "size_grip",
                               "shadow":[
                              {
                              "color": "#fff",
                              "blurRadius": 20,
                              "xOffset": 0,
                              "yOffset": 0,
                               "centralWidget": "centralwidget"
                               }
                          ],
                          "navigation":[
                               {
                                "minimize":"minimize_window_button",
                                 "close": "close_window_button",
                                 "restore":[
                                {
                                 "buttonName": "restore_window_button",
                                 "normalIcon": ":/icons/icons/square.svg",
                                 "maximizedIcon": ":/icons/icons/cil-window-restore.svg"
                                                }
                                              ],
                                         "moveWindow": "header_frame",
                                          "tittleBar": "header_frame"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
```

Comment: What "modern UI" is?

Comment: I suppose you're talking of that "QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets". If that's the case, I suggest you to avoid it, it's code is unmaintained, and poorly written and full of inconsistencies, including incomplete support for both PyQt *and* PySide, despite it says otherwise (which is the reason of your problem). Just reading [this report](https://github.com/KhamisiKibet/QT-PyQt-PySide-Custom-Widgets/issues/5) (and after having a short glimpse at the sources) made my eyes bleed.

Comment: I am not an expert but I will add to what @musicamante said, And If you meant [PyDracula - Modern GUI PySide6 / PyQt6](https://github.com/Wanderson-Magalhaes/Modern_GUI_PyDracula_PySide6_or_PyQt6) It is also wasn't created by a "professional programmer" quoting the author. Rather by a UX designer.